# Web browser plugin to filter pseudo-news and clickbait

Tags: web-browser, content-filtering

I would like to be able to filter news by their grade of actually being news.

Consider the following patterns - obviously these are not real events, anyway I personally do not an urge to learn more here:

- "Cooperation COULD happen, says an insider"
- "Cooperation as reported WILL NOT happen"
- "Cooperation DID NOT happen"
- " x PROMISED y"

Here's a real example of what today's [Google News](https://news.google.com/?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en) starting page displays to me:

- Elon Musk *could* face criminal as well as civil charges: Harvey Pitt
- Amazon *could* start a new movie-theater revolution with Landmark
  theatres
- Hearing aids *could* get way smarter with official Android
  support
- Where's love? 'Crazy Rich Asians' *could* usher in a new era of
  romantic comedies
- First galaxies to enter creation *could* be orbiting
  the Milky Way right now
- Apple's next-get iPhones *might* actually copy a Samsung phone for once

Also, it would be great to filter headlines using [click baiting](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-30671-1_72) tricks (sure enough much harder to recognize).

Is there a **web browser plugin** to stop this high entropy mess?

Similar to AdBlock, I want to avoid seeing links to such content.

Configurable criteria could be keywords, filter tolerance and ideally information entropy.

Comment: To me, it is unclear exactly what you are asking. Can you please provide more details of who the app you seek should work? Also, who gets to define "boring"?

Comment: @Mawg similarily to AdBlock, content related to pseudo-news should me removed. Configurable criteria could be keywords, filter tolerance and ideally information entropy.

Comment: That's a bit better ;-) In fact, I want to know the answer to this. Configurable  Is good. Could you please edit your question to add that, as not everyone might read the comments. Good luck with your search!